# How can I stop a long for loop when the widget (QDialog) running it is closed without multithreading?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a quite lengthy foreach loop in a QDialog. It basically looks like this:

```
foreach (xxx, xxx) {
    ... doSomeStuff ...
    QApplication::processEvents();

    if (m_cancelMapLoading) {
        break;
    }
}
```

m_cancelMapLoading is set to true by clicking a "Cancel" button. The QApplication::processEvents(); makes this possible.

This works quite fine, but if the dialog is closed as long as that foreach loop still runs, it continues running. I tried to set m_cancelMapLoading to true in each function closing the dialog, but this does not help.

I also tried to test not only for m_cancelMapLoading being true, but also for isVisible(). This actually stops the dialog, but it re-opens it at once without the GUI elements in it.

Unfortunately, QtConcurrent::run etc. can't be used for the function, because the data structures that are manipulated by the foreach loop are not thread safe.

Is there a convenient way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried assigning the variable m_cancelMapLoading to true in the class destructor?

Comment: Doing so, the loop simply continues to run.

Comment: Manually advancing the event loop can cause all sorts of terrible consequences.  Try placing the check for m_cancelMapLoading as the very first thing in your foreach loop and see if that "fixes" things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) and Qt's parent-child structure to your advantage here. QTimer with a timeout value of zero has a special meaning in Qt

> As a special case, a QTimer with a timeout of 0 will time out as soon
>   as all the events in the window system's event queue have been
>   processed. This can be used to do heavy work while providing a snappy
>   user interface:

So you could do something like

```
void Dialog::beginDoingStuff()
{
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processData());
    m_timer->start(0);
}

void Dialog::processData()
{
    // Perform one cycle of your process here
}
```

This will perform the processData() function in the same thread as the rest of the dialog, and when the dialog is destroyed by being closed, the timer will be deleted (because it's parent is the dialog), meaning the processing will stop.

Answer (score 0):

A good and quite easy way to unload your GUI from heavy processing is assigning it to another [thread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html) or [QtConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html).

You could then either poll a *"should-I-terminate-yet?"* variable or terminate the thread manually when it is no longer needed.

I highly recommend a parallel processing since offers better control rather than doing a "DoEvents"-like queue emptying.

Comment: I tried to do it by QtConcurrent, but the data structures that are manipulated by this function are not intended to be used by multithreading. This really caused a lot of problems that are probably not solvable by now :-(

Comment: uhm thread safety is required in order to move the workload there. I'm unsure whether to leave this as an answer then, anyway you should edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

We actually managed to solve the problem by connecting the dialog's finished signal to the click slot of the cancel button. This actually stops the loop in all circumstances.

We also introduced starting the function by a QTimer (for a nicer implementation not blocking the function where it's started), but this does not stop the loop (perhaps because we don't destroy the dialog when it's closed).

Thanks for all help :-)